# How to display values of one table which corresponds to a cell value of another table (with or without joins) in C# and .NET Core 3.1?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Would you kindly help me to get the desired output please? I am using .NET Core 3.1.

My function:

```
private List<Phrases_Clp> PhrasesStringToListPhrases_Clp(string phrases_codes)
{
     var listprhases = phrases_codes != null ? phrases_codes.Split(",") : new string[0];

     return _context.Phrases_Clps.Where(x => listprhases.Contains(x.Phrase_Numero)).ToList();
}
```

```
//GET: EvaluationRisque/Create
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrateur, Modificateur")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create()
{
    Create_Viewbags();

    var model = new EvaluationRisquesViewModel();

    var produitUtiliseByProduitId = await _context.Identification_Produit.FirstOrDefaultAsync();

    model.MentionsDanger = produitUtiliseByProduitId;

    model.List_Mentions_Danger = PhrasesStringToListPhrases_Clp(model.MentionsDanger.Mentions_Danger);

    return View(model);
}
```

```
<td>
    @foreach (var mention_danger in Model.List_Mentions_Danger)
    {
        <p> @mention_danger.Phrase_Numero : @mention_danger.Phrase_Libelle 
        </p>
    }
</td>
```

Table `identification_produit`:

| Id | Mentions_Danger |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | H203,H204 |
| 2 | H203,H204,H205 |
| 3 | H201,H202,H203 |

Table: `phrases_clp`

| Phrase_Numero | Phrase_Libelle |
| --- | --- |
| H203 | Explosif; danger d'incendie, d'effet de souffle ou de projection |
| H204 | Danger d'incendie ou de projection |
| H201 | Explosif; danger d'explosion en masse |

Desired output:

| Id | Mentions_Danger |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | H203:Explosif; danger d'incendie, d'effet de souffle ou de projection H204: Danger d'incendie ou de projection |
| 2 | H203Explosif; danger d'incendie, d'effet de souffle ou de projection H204: Danger d'incendie ou de projection, H205:aaaaaaaaaaaaaa |
| 3 | H201:bbbbbbbbbbbbbb, H202:ccccccccccccccccccc, H203:ddddddddddddddd |

Answer (score 0):

@Jérôme DE PORRES
I tried as below:

```
public class IdentificationProduit
    {        
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string MentionsDanger { get; set; }
        public List<PhrasesClp> PhrasesClps { get; set; }        
    }

public class PhrasesClp
    {
        [Key]
        public string PhraseNumero { get; set; }
        public string PhraseLibelle { get; set; }
        
        public List<IdentificationProduit> IdentificationProduits { get; set; }
    }
```

In controller:

```
var IdentificationProduits = _context.IdentificationProduit.Include(x=>x.PhrasesClps).ToList();
return View(IdentificationProduits);
```

In View：

```
@model List<IdentificationProduit>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Mentions_Danger</th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Id</td>
            <td>
                @for (int i = 0; i< item.PhrasesClps.Count; i++)
                {
                    @string.Format("{0}:{1},", item.PhrasesClps[0].PhraseNumero, item.PhrasesClps[0].PhraseLibelle);                  
                    
                }

            </td>
        </tr>

    }
</table>
```

DataBase：

[image]

[image]

[image]

Result：

[image]